# Node.js app running in Windows subsystem for Linux(Ubuntu) does not load values from .env file

Tags: node.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Node.js express app is running on Windows subsystem for Linux(Ubuntu). The environment variables are declared in .env file.

In the app, `process.env.PORT` is used which returns undefined.

Comment: How are you loading this .env file?

Comment: Using 'dotenv' npm module. `import * as dotenv from "dotenv";` `dotenv.config()`

Comment: Include that info in your question, as this is probably where your problem lies.

Comment: As far as I can tell, what you are doing should work.  Things to test: are you sure that you call `dotenv.config()` before you check `process.env.PORT?`; Is your `.env` file formatted correctly?; try `console.log(dotenv.config())` as it seems to return an object which shows what it has parsed, this may help; and finally, js is case sensetive, are you sure your environment variable is defined as `PORT` not `port`?

Comment: .env file is formatted correctly and this issue is only when the app is run on Windows subsystem for Linux.

Comment: on the dotenv page they recommend using `node -r dotenv/config` instead of ES-6 `import`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: If you test that on a JS file which only does `console.log(process.env.PORT)` and that is still undefined then I think you need to raise it with the dotenv guys.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. The order in which the variables from the `.env` file seem to be loading in different order. i.e: if I write a

```js
// using powershell
const t = require('dotenv').config();
console.log(t) 
/*
PATH=X
A=VALUE
B=VALUE2
*/

// using WSL
const t = require('dotenv').config();
console.log(t) 
/*
A=VALUE
B=VALUE2
PATH=X
*/
```